# Is there a quick way to get an XML element from a path?

Tags: python, xml-parsing

Is there a quick way to take this block of XML and extract the value of "version"?

```
   <xml>
   <creator version='1.0'>
     <program>BULK_EXTRACTOR</program>
     <version>1.0.3</version>
     <build_environment>
       <compiler>GCC 4.2</compiler>
       <compilation_date>2011-09-27T11:56:35</compilation_date>
       <library name="afflib" version="3.6.12"></library>
       <library name="libewf" version="20100226"></library>
     </build_environment>
    </creator>
    </xml>
```

I know that I can do this with Python's Beautiful Soup, but I'm look for a simple way to do it with the DOM.

Thanks!

Comment: Which `"version"` are you referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have *lxml* installed, you can use ElementTree which is included in the standard library:

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree
>>> doc = xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring(content)
>>> doc.findtext('creator/version')
'1.0.3'
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are looking for the version element, not the version attributes,
using [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/):

```
import lxml.etree as ET

content='''\
   <xml>
   <creator version='1.0'>
     <program>BULK_EXTRACTOR</program>
     <version>1.0.3</version>
     <build_environment>
       <compiler>GCC 4.2</compiler>
       <compilation_date>2011-09-27T11:56:35</compilation_date>
       <library name="afflib" version="3.6.12"></library>
       <library name="libewf" version="20100226"></library>
     </build_environment>
    </creator>
    </xml>
'''

doc=ET.fromstring(content)
version=doc.xpath('creator/version/text()')[0]
print(version)
# 1.0.3
```

To find the version attributes:

```
for elt in doc.xpath('//*[@version]'):
    print(elt.tag, elt.attrib.get('name'), elt.attrib.get('version'))
# ('creator', None, '1.0')
# ('library', 'afflib', '3.6.12')
# ('library', 'libewf', '20100226')
```